# Resize huge jpeg using no memory

Tags: delphi, resize, jpeg

I need to resize huge (up to 30000x30000) JPEG files using no RAM, speed doesn't matter, is there any way to do so? I tried different libraries (nativejpg and others) but they use all free RAM and and crash with errors like "Out of memory" or "Not enough storage is available to process this command". I even tried command line utility imagemagick, but it also uses gigabytes of memory.

Comment: @KenWhite No. That's not right. You can process the image in parts. You don't have to load the entire image into memory.

Comment: @KenWhite You know what I say is true. Let's focus on the concepts.

Comment: @Alex The problem with your question is that you seem to be asking for a library recommendation which is off topic. You ask if it is possible. Yes it is possible. Either you need to find a library, or do the image processing yourself.

Comment: I would never be able to write such a bit of code but even I understand how this could be possible.

Comment: @KenWhite Also, ImageMagick can handle this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php

Comment: @Alex ImageMagick can handle this. Why are you rejecting a solution that works.

Comment: Photoshop and the Mac preview are able to handle extremely large JPEGs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When resizing the segments you end up with a "border" around each segment. This happens because the resize doesn't take into account the neighboring pixels because they are on a different image. You would have to get around this by taking a large segment that what you need and then trim it back after the resize. These larger segments would overlap.

Comment: @Graymatter Obviously resizing algorithm has to be adjusted to take into account it is working on segments rather than whole picture, but that is not   very problematic issue.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That's only part of the issue. You need to figure out how to extract the portion of the image. You can't load the whole image because that needs to much memory. So your image library has to be capable of loading a portion of an image or loading using something like memory mapped files.

Comment: You didn't mention how you want the image resized. If you want it to be 1/2, 1/4 or 1/8 the original size, then it's a trivial operation that can be done with very little memory. Other sizes are possible, but require a bit more effort and memory.

Comment: @Graymatter depending on your needs, you can use existing Jpeg libraries to rescale image to smaller workable size. And then work with such image to get needed result.

Comment: @Graymatter Most image formats store data in chunks. While you will not get out of the box access to those chunks in common image processing libraries, you can write your own loading algorithms that will do so. But that would be far from trivial thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you have a look at `vips`. It is documented [here](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/doc/html/libvips/index.html).

I can create a 10000x10000 image of noise like this with ImageMagick

```
convert -size 10000x10000! xc:gray50 +noise poisson image.jpg
```

and check it is the correct size like this:

```
identify image.jpg
image.jpg JPEG 10000x10000 10000x10000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 154.9MB 0.000u
```

I can now use `vips` to resize the 10000x10000 image down to 2500x2500 like this

```
time vipsthumbnail image.jpg -s 2500 -o small.jpg --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 20.48 MB

real    0m1.974s
user    0m2.158s
sys     0m0.096s
```

**Note the memory usage peaked at just 20MB**

Check the result like this with ImageMagick

```
identify result.jpg
result.jpg JPEG 2500x2500 2500x2500+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.33MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Have a look at the Technical Note too, regarding performance and memory usage - [here](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Speed_and_Memory_Use).

You can also call it from `C` as well as the command line.

Comment: Hi, I'm the vips maintainer. I would use `vipsthumbnail` rather than `im_resize_linear`, the quality is much higher, it streams the image, and it's smart enough to use things like libjpeg shrink-on-load, so it's much quicker too. Try: `$ time vipsthumbnail big.jpg -s 2500 -o small.jpg --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 29.93 MB
real 0m2.362s
user 0m2.873s
sys 0m0.082s
`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with imagemagick if you turn on libjpeg shrink-on-load. Try:

```
$ identify big.jpg 
big.jpg JPEG 30000x30000 30000x30000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128MB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ time convert -define jpeg:size=2500x2500 big.jpg -resize 2500x2500 small.jpg
real    0m3.169s
user    0m2.999s
sys 0m0.159s
peak mem: 170MB
```

How this works: libjpeg has a great shrink-on-load feature. When you open an image, you can ask the library to downsample by x2, x4 or x8 during the loading process -- the library then just decodes part of each DCT block.

However, this feature must be enabled when the image is opened, you can't set it later. So `convert` needs a hint that when it opens `big.jpg`, it only needs to get an image of at least size 2500x2500 (your target size). Now all `-resize` is doing is shrinking a 3800x3800 pixel image down to 2500x2500, a pretty easy operation. You'll only need 1/64th of the CPU and memory.

As @mark-setchell said above, `vipsthumbnail` is even faster:

```
$ time vipsthumbnail big.jpg -s 2500 -o small.jpg --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 29.93 MB
real    0m2.362s
user    0m2.873s
sys 0m0.082s
```

Though the speedup is not very dramatic, since both systems are really just resizing 3800 -> 2500.

If you try tif instead, you do see a large difference, since there's no shrink-on-load trick you can use:

```
$ identify 360mp.tif 
360mp.tif TIFF 18000x18000 18000x18000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 972MB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ time convert 360mp.tif -resize 2500 x.tif
peak mem: 2.8 GB
real    0m8.397s
user    0m25.508s
sys 0m1.648s
$ time vipsthumbnail 360mp.tif -o x.tif -s 2500 --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 122.08 MB
real    0m2.583s
user    0m9.012s
sys 0m0.308s
```

Now `vipsthumbnail` is about 4x faster and needs only 1/20th of the memory.

Answer (score 1):

With built in Delphi Jpeg support you can load large jpeg image resampled to smaller size while loading without excessive usage of RAM.

Jpeg image Scale property can have following values `jsFullSize`, `jsHalf`, `jsQuarter`, `jsEighth`

```
procedure ScaleJpg(const Source, Dest: string);
var
  SourceImg, DestImg: TJPEGImage;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    SourceImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      SourceImg.Scale := jsEighth;
      SourceImg.LoadFromFile(Source);
      Bmp.Width := SourceImg.Width;
      Bmp.Height := SourceImg.Height;
      Bmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, SourceImg);
    finally
      SourceImg.Free;
    end;
    DestImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      DestImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
      DestImg.Assign(Bmp);
      DestImg.SaveToFile(Dest);
    finally
      DestImg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Once you have roughly rescaled image to size that can be comfortably processed in memory you can apply ordinary scaling algorithms to get the actual image size you want.