# Pillow's Image.open() MemoryError while opening big tiff file

Tags: python, image, tiff, python-imaging-library

I am writing a python script that will be running on the server and will resize images (namely Indesign links). It all works fine, except when I am trying to open bigger tiff files (800 MB).

I am using **Pillow's Image.open()** in order to resize it, but I am getting **MemoryError** error. I tried with other libraries like ImageMagick and tifffile with the same results. I could split it in smaller chunks, resize those and then combine them, but I have no idea how to do that without opening file first.

I searched extensively, but cannot find solution that would seem appropriate to my case. I was also observing memory consumption and it doesn't seem to be irregularly high. It's safe to say I am completely lost.

The whole trace goes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 87, in <module>
    convert()
  File "X:\Development\Python\zipper\converter.py", line 112, in convert
    if saveAsJPEG(file, name + ".jpg"): converted_images = updateCounter(all_images, converted_images)
  File "X:\Development\Python\zipper\converter.py", line 37, in saveAsJPEG
    print Image.open(a).size
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2266, in open
    im = factory(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 97, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 637, in _open
    self._seek(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 672, in _seek
    self.tag.load(self.fp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 458, in load
    data = ImageFile._safe_read(fp, size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 521, in _safe_read
    block = fp.read(min(size, SAFEBLOCK))
MemoryError
```

Thank you all for any help!

**--- EDIT**

This is the code that throws error

```
def saveAsJPEG(file, newfile):
    print "\nopening:", file
    try:
        with Image.open(file) as im:
            if not im.size[0] < size[0] or im.size[1] < size[1]:
                new_im = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                new_im.save(newfile, 'JPEG', quality=100, dpi=(72, 72))

                # Force a memory dump.  Otherwise memory will get cluttered up -> I am not sure if this is necessary as it doesn't seem to do anything. 
                del im
                del new_im
                collect()
                return True
    except:
        print "image is too big -> try something else. But what?"
        # this line below throws error (MemoryError). It was the same without try-except part before.
        Image.open(file)
```

The function is used in for-loop where "images" is array (list) of full file paths (X:\path\to\my\image.tiff)

```
for file in images:
    #gets extension
    name = basename(splitext(file)[0])
    ext = splitext(file)[1]

    # check for extension type and run appropriate function
    if ext == '.jpg' or ext == '.jpeg' or ext == '.tif' or ext == '.tiff':
        if saveAsJPEG(file, name + ".jpg"): converted_images = updateCounter(all_images, converted_images)

    del file, name, ext
```

Comment: Can you post the code that throws this error. Pillow's Image.open() should not throw this immediately after being called, as it only loads data into memory as it needs it.

Comment: Have a look at, and maybe vote for, my answer which uses `vips` here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115047/resize-huge-jpeg-using-no-memory/30118754#30118754

Comment: @steve - I added the code. And yeah, I also thought it shouldn't, as I was reading a post (from 1999) about loading parts of image: it was using Image.open() and then loading parts of this image.

MarkSetchell - thank you, I will take a look :)